# CMake target_compile_definitions add comma separated list for value

Tags: cmake

I wish to replicate in CMake the following:

```c
#define mydef a, b, c
```

However

```CMake
target_compile_definitions(myproject PRIVATE mydef="a, b, c")
```

seems to result in

```c
#define mydef "a, b, c"
```

What would be the correct syntax to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the whole parameter including the name of the symbol you want to define:

```
target_compile_definitions(myproject PRIVATE "mydef=a, b, c")
```